# Terraform plugins causing push issues with git

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've been working through a LinuxAcademy lab for terraform using docker containers, which has all been going fine. I've been putting all my code into a private repo so I can refer to it and pull it down onto my home workstation off the linuxacademy lab servers.

I've run into an issue after creating an S3 bucket using a terraform script, it's pretty simple code:

```
# Create random id

resource "random_id" "tf_bucket_id" {
  byte_length = 2
}

# Create the bucket

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf_code" {
  bucket = "${var.project_name}-${random_id.tf_bucket_id.dec}"
  acl = "private"
  force_destroy = true

  tags {
    Name = "tf_bucket"
  }
}
```

If I do a terraform init it downloads the plugins:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins on https://releases.hashicorp.com...
- Downloading plugin for provider "random" (2.0.0)...
- Downloading plugin for provider "aws" (2.2.0)...
```

And a terraform apply runs the code successfully:

```
random_id.tf_bucket_id: Creating...
  b64:         "" => "<computed>"
  b64_std:     "" => "<computed>"
  b64_url:     "" => "<computed>"
  byte_length: "" => "2"
  dec:         "" => "<computed>"
  hex:         "" => "<computed>"
random_id.tf_bucket_id: Creation complete after 0s (ID: 3Ok)
aws_s3_bucket.tf_code: Creating...
  acceleration_status:         "" => "<computed>"
  acl:                         "" => "private"
  arn:                         "" => "<computed>"
  bucket:                      "" => "la-terraform-56553"
  bucket_domain_name:          "" => "<computed>"
  bucket_regional_domain_name: "" => "<computed>"
  force_destroy:               "" => "true"
  hosted_zone_id:              "" => "<computed>"
  region:                      "" => "<computed>"
  request_payer:               "" => "<computed>"
  tags.%:                      "" => "1"
  tags.Name:                   "" => "tf_bucket"
  versioning.#:                "" => "<computed>"
  website_domain:              "" => "<computed>"
  website_endpoint:            "" => "<computed>"
aws_s3_bucket.tf_code: Creation complete after 5s (ID: la-terraform-56553)

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

bucket_name = la-terraform-56553
```

Here's the problem, if I go to commit the changes git wants to commit the .terraform/plugins directory, along with the plugins themselves. But the plugins are too big for git to handle, so I get this error:

```
terraform@foobarserver:~/repos/private/terraform$ git push
Counting objects: 13, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 28.65 MiB | 1.68 MiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), completed with 3 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: c7cf151dfa233bfff86c3191eb63b5d9
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File terraform/aws/LA_project/storage/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.2.0_x4 is 111.33 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To git@github.com:foobaruser/private.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:foobaruser/private.git'
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get git to ignore the plugins. I have tried adding a gitignore file with the directory explictly listed, but the directory still appears when I run "git status". I'm tearing my hair out as I don't have this issue at work where we use bitbucket, if terraform automatically downloads the plugins like this how are other people using terraform in git without masses of large plugin files everywhere?

*edit*
Thank you SO much to the commentator below, somehow I'd missed that in all the terraform installation and update process. Installed the stock .gitignore file in my root terraform directory and voila, no more issues. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the .gitignore file generated by [gitignore.io/api/terraform](https://www.gitignore.io/api/terraform) - give that a shot and see if it helps.

Make sure you commit and push your updated `.gitignore` file first before trying `git status` and making a separate commit for the rest of your files.

Comment: I have upped it but due to my low rep it doesn't publicly change the score. I am very thankful though!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to fix this issue.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch .terraform/'
```

This command works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your .gitignore file is like this

```
# Local .terraform directories
/.terraform/

# .tfstate files
*.tfstate
*.tfstate.*

# Crash log files
crash.log
crash.*.log

# Exclude all .tfvars files, which are likely to contain sensitive data, such as
# password, private keys, and other secrets. These should not be part of version 
# control as they are data points which are potentially sensitive and subject 
# to change depending on the environment.
*.tfvars
*.tfvars.json

# Ignore override files as they are usually used to override resources locally and so
# are not checked in
override.tf
override.tf.json
*_override.tf
*_override.tf.json

# Include override files you do wish to add to version control using negated pattern
# !example_override.tf

# Include tfplan files to ignore the plan output of command: terraform plan -out=tfplan
# example: *tfplan*

# Ignore CLI configuration files
.terraformrc
terraform.rc
.terraform.lock.hcl
```

2. Run `ls -a` in your terminal to view the hidden files in the directory. You will find the .git folder.
3. In your terminal, delete the .git folder that was automatically created when you ran `git init` in a bid to push with the command below:
   `rm -rf .git`
4. Run `git init` to initialize again since we have deleted the previous .git folder. Then, try doing the process of pushing it to the repository again by running "git remote add origin.....", "git add .", "git commit -m .....", and finally "git push". Pushing it should work now.